# MariaDB DELETE not removing all rows

Tags: mariadb, php

I'm managing a MariaDB server and I noticed that an application run a DELETE query in a table each time the entity was saved and then it will insert the new rows referenced that entity. Sometimes happen that some rows are kept on the table and after the insert the row results duplicated.
The table was missing a PK so i added an auto increment one, but the problem persist.
I can't modify the application so i can't add a transaction to the DELETE/INSERT operation.
How can i avoid this type of duplication?

## Edit 2019-06-06

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ipr` (
  `id` int(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prid` int(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `seq` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comm` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descr` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `chapter_id` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineitem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_aipk` int(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`custom_aipk`),
  KEY `ipr_id_idx` (`id`),
  KEY `ipr_productid_idx` (`prid`),
  KEY `lineitem_id` (`lineitem_id`),
  KEY `idx_chapter` (`chapter_id`(10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1261 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Query from `mysql.general_log`:

```sql
DELETE FROM ipr WHERE id='123456';

INSERT INTO ipr (id, prid, seq, qty, price, comm, descr, chapter_id, lineitem_id) 
         VALUES ('123456','648',1,'1.000',0,'Comment','','891',651);
[...]
INSERT INTO ipr (id, prid, seq, qty, price, comm, descr, chapter_id, lineitem_id) 
         VALUES ('123456','698',10,'1.000',0,'Comment 3','','897',692);
```

## Edit 2019-06-07

The database schema of this application don't use any foreign key and i forgot to say that `ipr.id` **should be** (but is not) a reference to the main entity on another table.

The relation should be `myentitytbl.id -> reference many on -> ipr.id`.
So i cannot follow *jynus* suggestion.

At the moment I'm not searching a workaround to prevent row duplication, I badly explained myself.The problem that I'm concerning is that MariaDB when receive a `DELETE` query doesn't delete all rows.

For example if i have 15 rows in `ipr` table with `id = 213` when the application run `DELETE FROM ipv WHERE id = 213;` only 5 rows got deleted and the other 10 don't get deleted, then when the application run all the `INSERT` i will have $newrow+10 that don't get deleted by the previous statement.

Comment: Add a unique constraint on the entity reference and hope that the application, which you cannot modify, can handle the resulting exceptions.

Comment: For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the specific queries applied.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what queries are sent to the database.

Comment: I have added also the INSERT query

Comment: "The problem that I'm concerning is that MariaDB when receive a DELETE query doesn't delete all rows." -> I don't understand that.

Comment: I have added an example that maybe can explain better the problem